# Java Sockets: How to read/write Objects and strings?

Tags: sockets, object, stream

I am attempting to write a client/server program where the client can:
  *Write a string to server
  *Receive an Object from server

and the server can:
  *Receive a string from a client
  *Send an object to the client.

However, my attempts so far have proved fruitless and I am quite frustrated. I am sure I am making a fundamental flaw, but being so new to Socket programming I just cannot see where I am going wrong.

Is there anything wrong with my choice of streams, or is there a better way of using streams which I have not picked up on?

The object I am sending is serialised, although the object is never written/read as the server hangs on the readUTF()

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
//Used to receive a string input from client side
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
// Used to output an object to client side
ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

// This is never executed..
clientInput = input.readUTF();
oo.writeObject(book);
```

**Client Side code:**

```
        // Used to read object from server side
        input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        // Used to read input from command line
        keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // Used to send string to server
        output = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        cmdInput = keyboard.readLine();
        // Write to server, this executes at runtime.
        output.writeUTF(cmdInput);                              
        // Object is never sent, this line is not executed.
        book = (Book)input.readObject();
```

Comment: Since you're using ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream, I assume you want to use TCP. Can you include the code where you create clientSocket for both the server and the client? You are using theServerSocket class for the server, right?

Comment: Yes I am using the ServerSocket for server and Socket for client. The client server connection is working fine as I was able to pass strings simply. It is when I added object functionality that it started to break.

Comment: But your client code gets stuck **before** you call writeObject...

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would be better off using a web service kit (e.g. Apache CXF) than doing this yourself.

In specific, try calling `flush()` on your output stream in the client.

Comment: I have tried calling flush in the client, it made no changes. Also, for this problem it is suitable I develop only within the JDK library.

Comment: In java 1.6 there is a full web service kit in the JDK.